# Calling named routes in laravel tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit, laravel-5

consider the following:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class HomeRouteTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testVisitTheHomePage()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());

    }

    public function testVisitTheAboutPage()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/about');
        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
    }
}
```

Is there away, not that I have seen documented >.>, to do something like:

```
$response = $this->call('GET', 'home.about');
$this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
```

Or .... Is that how you do it?

The error I get is:

```
vagrant@scotchbox:/var/www$ phpunit
PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

FF

Time: 3.41 seconds, Memory: 14.25Mb

There were 2 failures:

1) HomeRouteTest::testVisitTheHomePage
Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 200.

/var/www/tests/HomeRouteTest.php:12

2) HomeRouteTest::testVisitTheAboutPage
Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 200.

/var/www/tests/HomeRouteTest.php:19

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 2.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very late response, but I think what you're looking for is:

```
$this->route('GET', 'home.about');
$this->assertResponseOk(); // Checks that response status was 200
```

For routes with parameters, you can do this:

```
$this->route('GET', 'users.show', ['id' => 3]); // (goes to '/users/3')
```

I needed this to test some ghastly routes I'm working with, which look like this:

```
Route::resource(
    '/accounts/{account_id}/users',
    'AccountsController@users',
    [
        'parameters' => ['account_id'],
        'names'      => [
            'create'  => 'users.create',
            'destroy' => 'users.destroy',
            'edit'    => 'users.edit',
            'show '   => 'users.show',
            'store'   => 'users.store',
            'update'  => 'users.update',
        ]
    ]
);
```

To make sure that my routes and redirects went to the right page I did this:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function users_index_route_loads_correct_page()
{
    $account = Account::first();

    $response = $this->route('get', 'users.index', ['account_id' => $account->id]);
    $this->assertResponseOk()
        ->seePageIs('/accounts/' . $account->id . '/users');
}
```

To make sure I was using the right view file (we all make copy-paste errors, right?), I did this:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function users_index_route_uses_expected_view()
{
    $account = Account::first();

    $response = $this->route('get', 'users.index', ['account_id' => $account->id]);

    $view = $response->original; // returns View instance
    $view_name = $view->getName();

    $this->assertEquals($view_name, 'users.index'); 
}
```

If it weren't for the Structure feature in PHPStorm and the documentation from Laravel 4.2 that I stumbled over, I don't think I would have ever figured out how to test those routes. I hope this saves someone else a bit of time.

Comment: This no longer works in Laravel 5.4 - Call to undefined method route()

Comment: The method to call on the later versions of laravel is call().

Comment: call() return 404 it does not behave the same as route()

Answer (score 9):

**This solution works for any Laravel 5 version to my knowledge. Especially Laravel 5.4+ unlike the other solution mentioned here.**

If your named route has parameters, you can just do this:

```
$response = $this->get(route('users.show', [
    'user' => 3,
]));

$response->assertStatus(200);
```

If your named route has no parameters then you can just do this:

```
$response = $this->get(route('users.index'));

$response->assertStatus(200);
```

Nice and simple.

Answer (score 3):

from Laravel 5.2 up to Laravel 10, you can try this to call named routing:

```php
$this->call('POST', route('some_named_routing', $parameters));
```

or

```php
$this->post(route('some_named_routing', $parameters));
```

more information can be found in official Laravel framework of github

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.2.0/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php

Answer (score -1):

To be honest I don't see any reason to test names route. Named routes are rather for easier use inside application and you should rather test concrete url and not names route to make sure you are using correct url.

If you need to really test named route, I would create helper function for that with simple array:

```
protected function getNamedRoute($name) 
{
   $routes = [
        'home.about' => '/about',
   ];

   return $routes[$name]; 
}
```

and then in your test:

```
public function testVisitTheHomePage()
{
    $response = $this->call('GET', $this->getNamedRoute('home.about'));
    $this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
}
```

The second thing is that you can make those tests a bit cleaner, you don't need to use:

```
$response = $this->call('GET', '/');
$this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
```

you can use:

```
$this->visit('/')->seeStatusCode(200);
```

For me it's much more legible and you can write less code to achieve same.

Comment: I don't really see how your test actually tests any thing. I already have routes defined in my system, you just seem to be testing the fact that routes names exist ...

Comment: The reason to test named routes is so that when the URLs change due to a refactor, the tests keep working without being changed (as long as the name of the route does not change).

Comment: @Julian But what in case you created API for 3rd parties and one of developers will change the route url without actually notifying 3rd parties? Tests will pass (because they would use named routes) but your application won't be usable for 3rd parties because in their apps they are not using obviously named routes but url.

Comment: You misunderstand me. You said "I don't see any reason to test named routes"; I gave you one. I didn't say this was the only one nor that this is what you should always do in every case. Every app is different and testing named routes will or will not make sense depending on your business rules.